# How to identify the image is greyscale image or color image in c#

Tags: c#, image, colors, grayscale

I have requirement of validating a bulk number of images (jpg, tif, png) in a folder with height attributes. but the validation rules are different for color images and grayscale images.

but My Problem is

How to identify the image is grayscale image or color image in c#?

at least where to start?

Comment: I believe the Image or Bitmap class contains an ImageFormat property that specifies the bits-per-pixel.  That alone wont be enough though.  You probably need to scan through each pixel and make sure that r==g==b

Comment: can you please provided me so peace of code

Comment: no.  there are tons of examples on the web demonstrating this concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool IsGreyScale(Bitmap YourCurrentBitmap)
{
Color c;
for(int i=0; i < YourCurrentBitmap.Width; i++)
     for(int j=0; j < YourCurrentBitmap.Height; j++)
          {
               c = YourCurrentBitmap.GetPixel(i,j);
               if(!(c.R == c.G == c.B)) return false;
          }
return true;
}
```

But this method is relatively slow though.